# For what human reason was Christ crucified?

Tags: history

I know that from God the Father's perspective, Christ had to die for the sins of the elect.

However, from a secular perspective, why was Christ crucified?

I know that the Jews were unhappy with Christ claiming to be God -- but secularly, that only makes him insane, not worthy of the death penalty.

There was the time that he over turned a bunch of tables in the temple; but that too seems like a misdemeanor / felony, not death by crucifixion.

Given that he was crucified with "King of the Jews" was the reason that he was guilty of "trying to overthrow Rome" ?

Comment: The ruling Jews were religious not secular. What makes you think "secularly" had much if any bearing?

Comment: @Caleb I think Matthew's point is that the crucifixion was carried out by the Romans.  He is asking for the reason why they would carry it out - under which specific law did Jesus break.  It's not often that the Romans would just kill someone because the majority of people didn't like this specific person.  We are taught that Pilate wanted to not have a riot.  However, under what secular law / reason did Pilate execute Jesus?  I'm pretty confident that the answer is not biblical.

Comment: @Matthew7.7 Please revise your question per your comments below to get relevant answers.

Comment: **that only makes him insane, not worthy of the death penalty** ...  Not in any Christian belief.  This site is about Christian beliefs, teachings, and doctrine.  Your premise is untenable within the context of Q&A on this stack.  Lose it and the question may be reopened.

Comment: "trying to overthrow Rome" ?  Why did you put that in scare quotes?  What you you mean by that?  Please be direct and do not attempt to be clever or obtuse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the "political" or "social" reasons Jesus was killed as opposed to the theological significance or motivation of his death.

Recall that the Judean state had been in tumult since the Maccabean period. The expectation of many Jews for a political "Messiah" (i.e. someone "anointed" to reclaim the throne of David) was at odds with the imperial power of Rome. When Jesus proclaimed the inbreaking of the "kingdom of God/Heaven" he was making a political statement over and against the "kingdom of Rome." This is why the disciples ask Jesus:

> Lord, are you at this time going to restore the kingdom to Israel?" - Acts 1:6

They were expecting Jesus to destroy the Romans and reestablish the Davidic kingship. This is also why it was so confusing for the disciples that Jesus would be *killed*—especially after, for example, the triumphal entry, which imitated (or mocked, depending on who you ask) a General returning to his city from a victorious campaign. The Qumran community had basically the same Messianic understanding, except they expected *two* messiahs, one a political leader, and the other a priestly figure. The two Jewish revolts after Jesus also provide nice examples. The first, Rome crushed in 70 CE with the destruction of the Temple in Jerusalem, and in 74 CE at Masada. The second, in 132-135 CE ended with the death of Simon bar Kokhba, the rebel leader.

As such, Jesus was arrested and killed essentially for for *sedition*--the Jewish leaders who were collaborating with Rome wished to keep the peace, and the best way to do that was to silence dissenting voices. The whole "claiming to be God" bit was really more of an excuse (or anyway, according to my understanding of the text).

I would also caution placing too much blame on "the Jews," that is, "the Jewish people," since the Jewish leadership was a very small and powerful group of elites. Parts of the NT (particularly GJohn) border on anti-Semitic at times, but we should be sure to consider the historical *sitz* of such writings and understand that it likely is a reflection of tension between Jewish and Christian groups in the late 1st/early 2nd centuries, and not necessarily perfectly historically accurate.

Comment: I was with you right up until you make the claim that parts of the NT are not necessarily historically accurate. I agree with the point you are trying to make about blaming the Jews, but not for that reason!  I would suggest your answer is valuable, and would be more broadly appreciated if left off before the last sentence.

Comment: John is a lot easier to understand when you read "the Jews" as "the Jewish leaders", not "the Jewish people."

Answer (score 7):

It was the chief priests and pharisees that wanted Jesus arrested. Matthew 26:47 :

> While he was still speaking, Judas, one of the Twelve, arrived. With him was a large crowd armed with swords and clubs, sent from the chief priests and the elders of the people

"that only makes him insane, not worthy of the death penalty"

Torah, Leveticus 24:16 makes it clear that blasphemy carries a death sentence (although via stoning). More likely, though, he was simply seen as a rebel and a risk, potentially a flash-point for a more visible and popular uprising. That would be plenty of reason for the religious and political leaders to see... *economy* in a prompt but final action.

I don't know about a *secular* reason, but: perhaps a *political* reason that Pilate may have acquiesced to the demands of the Jewish priests; [supposedly](http://www.livius.org/pi-pm/pilate/pilate01.htm) there is evidence to support some previous hoo-hah involving a row between Pilate and the locals relating to some pagan shields - Pilate refused to remove them, the locals complained to the emperor, the emperor expressed his anger at Pilate's approach. This could lead us to suspect that maybe Pilate didn't want a re-run that could put his position (and likely: life) in jeopardy, so was willing to yield a bit to the locals. Especially if it looked like a riot was likely otherwise.

Comment: I think I poorly phrased my question. In a modern world, if someone were to be executed, there'd be an official reason: "i.e. this person is guilty of murder." For the crucifixion of Christ, what was the "official/legalistic" reason?

Comment: @Matthew7.7 I think you're over-complicating the legal system of the time; I'm not a historian, but I rather suspect I've already covered that. Essentially, "because we say so". John 19:7 is probably the closest the Bible gets to any *official* reason: "The Jewish leaders replied, “We have a law, and according to our law he ought to die, because he claimed to be the Son of God!”". That, however, is not a "secular" reason - but is perhaps a *political* reason.

Comment: @Matthew7.7 the Romans, perhaps sensibly, were *fairly* (not entirely) sensitive towards local politics - oppressive tactics tending to incite the crowds, etc.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your original response. Is the following correct: the Jews' official reason for killing Christ was "blasphemy for calling himself God." The Jews lacked the power to crucify Christ; so they twisted Pilates arm via some political means.

Comment: @Matthew7.7 it is unclear how much *explicit* arm-twisting was required (versus just knowing how the land lies), but essentially: yes

Comment: @MarcGravell "I don't know about a secular reason" - if you don't know this, then you shouldn't answer a question titled with it - IMHO.

Comment: @DanAndrews, I'm not even sure what "a secular reason" means.  But the spirit of the question is asking why, from the Roman government's perspective, was Jesus crucified.  This answers that nicely, and a *political* reason satisfies the question.

Comment: @DanAndrews: I think this answer correctly points out that it wasn't a "secular" reason at all, it was in fact a religious law that was trespassed and, with some political finagling, enforced. The question is not asking for a "secular perspective", it is asking for something that our culture might have but for which there was no equivalent in the structures of the day.

Comment: @Caleb Are you sure about that?  "However, from a **secular perspective**, why was Christ crucified?"

Comment: @DanAndrews: Yes, I'm actually rather sure. The OP clarified their own poor wording on this in [another comment](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9127/what-is-the-secular-reason-christ-was-crucified/9128#comment25382_9128) to mean "official/legalistic". Combine that with their acceptance of this answer and I think a pretty solid case can be made that your objection doesn't stand. What the OP was after when they used the word "perspective" was not the same thing as the issue we enforce around here whereby answers are required to match the perspective of the question.

Comment: @Caleb I read the question and this answer - before commenting.  I did not read all of the comments first.  Maybe the OP need to revise the question?

Comment: I seem to recall that Pilate had previously overplayed his hand, being arrogant and riding roughshod over local sensibilities (I forget the details, but I don't recall anything about Pagan shields: may have been that, may have been something else), and had got in trouble for it. So this time he was playing it safe. But then, the story as reported is almost certainly mythologised to some extent too. The night trial. The washing of the hands. The cock crowing. It's all a series of set pieces.

Comment: @TRiG indeed, one could easily lose sight of the concrete evidence on such things.

Answer (score 1):

**For what human reason was Christ crucified?**

> Luke 22:2  And the chief priests and scribes sought how they might
>   kill him; for they feared the people.

Essentially you have a ruling class of Jews who hated Jesus for political reasons. They saw him as rising in popularity and subsequently their own social and political positions were threatened.

They brought false accusations against him to the Romans as they were not legally allowed to put anyone to death.

> Matthew 26:59  Now the chief priests, and elders, and all the council,
>   sought false witness against Jesus, to put him to death;

They thought they had the perfect charge to use against Jesus with what they saw as blasphemy.

> Matthew 26:65  Then the high priest rent his clothes, saying, He hath
>   spoken blasphemy; what further need have we of witnesses? behold, now
>   ye have heard his blasphemy.

They were politically astute enough to recognize that the Roman administrator would not consider blasphemy a serious offense so they sought to present Jesus to Pilate as a promoter of sedition and rebellion.

> Luke 23:2  And they began to accuse him, saying, We found this fellow
>   perverting the nation, and forbidding to give tribute to Caesar,
>   saying that he himself is Christ a King.

Pilate was not so easily misled.

> Matthew 27:18  For he knew that for envy they had delivered him.

Pilate had himself been twice before forced to back down from a ruling he had made by the appeal of the Jewish leaders to Caesar. As a result, he understood the limits of what he could do. He attempted to get out of the corner the Jews had backed him into.

> Matthew 27:21-22  The governor answered and said unto them, Whether of
>   the twain will ye that I release unto you? They said, Barabbas.
>   Pilate saith unto them, What shall I do then with Jesus which is
>   called Christ? They all say unto him, Let him be crucified.

Pilate calculated that he did not have the political capital to force his will against the Jewish leaders who had twice before got him in trouble with his boss.

What human reasons? Envy, hatred, mob mentality, and cowardice.